# Please explain uniform distribution to me

Tags: statistics

I am confused about Uniform Distribution 
why does $$P(v < 2b1)$$

equal 2b1 ?

Comment: The game theory question deals with the wider theory and why we do certain calculations, this deal with individual calculations and how to do them
which calculations to do vs how to do them

Answer (score -1):

I guess $v$ is a random variable of uniform distribution *on the interval $[0,1]$*. Then, if $0\le b_1\le 1/2$, we indeed have

> $P(v<2b_1)=$ length of $[0,2b_1)$ which is $2b_1$.

Comment: thanks
but How do you get the length ?

Comment: We have $P(v\in S)=\lambda(S)$ for any measurable $S$ where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on the line, i.e. the length. The full event has probability $P(v\in [0,1])=1$ and the empty event has $P(v\in empty)=0$.